# PK and FK Modeling Issues

Tags: mysql, database-design, data-modeling

I have a table (`CONFIG_USERS`) that stores informations about configurations that a user defined on our products.
`PRODUCT_ID` identifies one of our products, `USER_ID` identifies a user, `CONFIG_ID` identifies a Configuration, by example `'ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGON'`. These columns are PK on this table.

[image: CONFIG_USERS Table]

Now, I'd like to provide a "User Friendly Name" to each configuration we have, on various languages.

So, I created the table `DEF_CONFIG_LANGUAGES`, where we uniquely identity a language and it's name, by example, `en-US | English`, `pt-BR | Portugues Brasileiro`, and so on.

[image: DEF_CONFIG_LANGUAGES]

And now, I need to model a 3rd table where we will store **User Friendly Description** of each available config, **in each language that is available** on DEF_CONFIG_LANGUAGES, something like this:

[image: DEF_CONFIGURATIONS]

But I'm in trouble on how to correctly model this relation. Modeling `DEF_CONFIG_LANGUAGES_TO_DEF_CONFIGURATIONS_FK` as a 'Non-Identifying' relation makes PK on DEF_CONFIGURATIONS to be only CONFIG_ID and PRODUCT_ID, that not allows me to add more than on Language Description for a CONFIG_ID. See:

[image: Non-Identifying DEF_CONFIG_LANGUAGES_TO_DEF_CONFIGURATIONS_FK]

Making the `DEF_CONFIG_LANGUAGES_TO_DEF_CONFIGURATIONS_FK` as a 'Identifying FK', makes the `PK` on `DEF_CONFIGURATIONS` to be `CONFIG_ID`, `PRODUCT_ID` and `LANG_ID`, thus allowing me to add various languages descriptions to each config... But, is also add the `LANG_ID` column on table `CONFIG_USERS`, and this is not desirable since these table store config_values that is independent to the locale/language.

See:
[image: Identifying DEF_CONFIG_LANGUAGES_TO_DEF_CONFIGURATIONS_FK]

The ideia here is to build a SQL that will be something like this:

```
SELECT A.CONFIG_ID, A.CONFIG_VALUE, B.CONFIG_NAME, B.CONFIG_DESCRIPTION, B.CONFIG_HELP
  FROM CONFIG_USERS A
  LEFT JOIN DEF_CONFIGURATIONS B 
    ON B.PRODUCT_ID = A.PRODUCT_ID
   AND B.CONFIG_ID = A.CONFIG_ID
   AND B.LANG_ID = :langId
 WHERE A.PRODUCT_ID = :productID and A.USER_ID = :userID;
```

The parameter 'langId' will be loaded dynamically according to the OS current locale, so, I don't want the column LANG_ID on CONFIG_USERS table.

Maybe I'm missing something very basic here, but I really didn't realize the correct way to model this without breaking any recommended practice on Database Modeling.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to sort this out I had to tell the whole story.

---

```
-- Language LNG exists.
--
language {LNG}
      PK {LNG}
```

```
-- User USR prefers to communicate
-- in language LNG.
--
user {USR, LNG}
  PK {USR}

FK {LNG} REFERENCES language {LNG}
```

```
-- Product PRO exists.
--
product {PRO}
     PK {PRO}
```

```
-- User USR is allowed to use product PRO.
--
user_product {USR, PRO}
          PK {USR, PRO}

FK1 {USR} REFERENCES user    {USR}
FK2 {PRO} REFERENCES product {PRO}
```

```
-- Configuration parameter CFG exists.
--
config {CFG}
    PK {CFG}
```

```
-- Configuration parameter CFG applies
-- to product PRO.
--
product_config {PRO, CFG}
            PK {PRO, CFG}

FK1 {PRO} REFERENCES product {PRO}
FK2 {CFG} REFERENCES config  {CFG}
```

```
-- User USR set configuration parameter CFG
-- of product PRO to value VAL.
--
user_product_config {USR, PRO, CFG, VAL}
                 PK {USR, PRO, CFG}

           FK1 {PRO, CFG} REFERENCES
product_config {PRO, CFG}

         FK2 {USR, PRO} REFERENCES
user_product {USR, PRO}
```

```
-- In language LNG, configuration parameter CFG
-- is named NME, described as DES, with help HLP.
--
config_language {CFG, LNG, NME, DES, HLP}
             PK {CFG, LNG}

FK1 {CFG} REFERENCES config   {CFG}
FK2 {LNG} REFERENCES language {LNG}
```

```sql
-- User USR set configuration parameter CFG
-- of product PRO to value VAL. In user's
-- preferred language LNG the parameter
-- is named NME, described as DES, with help HLP.
--
CREATE VIEW user_product_config_language
AS
SELECT a.USR
     , a.PRO
     , a.CFG
     , a.VAL
     , b.LNG
     , c.NME
     , c.DES
     , c.HLP
FROM user_product_config AS a
JOIN user                AS b ON b.USR = a.USR
JOIN config_language     AS c ON c.CFG = a.CFG AND c.LNG = b.LNG ;
```

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
AK = Alternate Key (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement the @Damir [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65214640/1015482), here is the model of it's approach.

Thanks!

[image: Model]